# How many blocks can be made of a subset of S in a Steiner system

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

Assume a *Steiner system* with parameters $t, k, n$, i.e., $S(t,k,n)$. By definition, the system is an $n$-element set $S$ together with a set of $k$-element subsets of $S$ (called *blocks*) such that each $t$-element subset of $S$ is contained in exactly one block.

Now consider a Steiner system $S(t,k,n)$ and a subset $X \subset S$ with cardinality $|X| = c > k$. The question I am interested in is:

- How many blocks of the system consist exclusively of elements of $X$?

An expression given at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system#Properties) quantifies how many blocks include a $c$-element subset of S and holds for values of $c \leq t$.

I am wondering whether there is an expression for all values of $c \in \{t+1,\dots,k\}$ for the question stated above. I would think that the answer depends on the construction method. Are there constructions for which one can give such an expression?

Comment: "An expression given at Wikipedia quantifies how many blocks include a $c$-element subset of S and holds for values of $c \leq k$": do you mean that there is a formula for the number of blocks containing a $c$-element subset for $c \leq t$? There is not an exact formula for values $t < c \leq k$ (this number will not be constant for all $c$-subsets).

Comment: You can make some progress towards investigating this question by considering the **complementary design** of your Steiner triple system. Do you know what this is? How much design theory are you familiar with?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have fixed the typos. I am familiar with the very basics in design theory. So a complementary design $D^c$ will have all point-block incidence relations that that $D$ does not have. How does this help? Also, if we use a $t$-design instead of a Steiner system then the answer to my question is easier, i.e., a constant number?

Comment: In other words, are you asking 1: if there is a formula for how many blocks **contain** a set of size $c$ for $c \in \{t+1,\ldots, k\}$? 2: if there is a formula for how many bocks **are contained** in a set of size $c$ for $c \in \{k+1\ldots, n\}$? (your reference to "the question above" is somewhat confusing given the $c$ values you describe in the final part of your post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $\mathcal{D}$ be an $S(t,k,n)$, in other words, a $t$-$(n,k,1)$ design, then the complementary design $\mathcal{D}^{c}$, obtained by replacing each block with its complement, is also a $t$-design (though not a Steiner system), in other words it is a $t$-$(n,n-k,\lambda^{\prime})$ for some $\lambda^{\prime}$.

The Wikipedia result you give says that if $\mathcal{D}$ is an $S(t,k,n)$ then for each $0 \leq i \leq t$, we have that there are
$$\lambda_{i} = {n-i \choose t-i}/{k-i \choose t-i}$$
blocks of $\mathcal{D}$ containing any fixed $i$-subset of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$.
This is however a special case of a result that holds for any $t$-$(n,k,\lambda)$ design that gives this value as
$$\lambda_{i} = \lambda{n-i \choose t-i}/{k-i \choose t-i}$$

If we want to know how many blocks of $\mathcal{D}$ are **contained** in some fixed $j$-set $X$, this number will be constant over all possible $j$-sets as long as $n-t \leq j \leq n$.

To see this, we should realize that this is equivalent to asking how many blocks of $\mathcal{D}^{c}$ *contain* $X^{c}$ (or rather consider $X^{c}$ to be an arbitrary $(n-j)$-subset).
In this case, modifying the formula above with the parameters of $\mathcal{D}^{c}$, we have
$$\lambda^{\prime}_{j} = 
\lambda^{\prime}\frac{{n-(n-j) \choose t-(n-j)}}{{n-k-(n-j) \choose t-(n-j)}} = 
\lambda^{\prime}\frac{{j \choose j-(n-t)}}{{j-k \choose j-(n-t)}} = 
\lambda^{\prime}\frac{{j \choose n-t}}{{j-k \choose j-(n-t)}}$$
where $\lambda^{\prime}$ is given by
$$\lambda^{\prime} = \sum_{i=0}^{t} (-1)^{i}{t \choose i}\lambda_{i}.$$
(See Godsil, Combinatorial Design Theory Lemma 7.3.1)

Godsil actually gives an easier formula:
$$\lambda_{j}^{\prime} = \sum_{i=0}^{j} (-1)^{i}{j \choose i}\lambda_{i}$$
(in both of these formulas the $\lambda_{i}$ are given by the earlier formula $\lambda_{i} = {n-i \choose t-i}/{k-i \choose t-i}$).

**Note:** if $j < k$ then $X$ cannot contain any blocks of $\mathcal{D}$; and if $k \leq j < n-t$ then the number of blocks contained in $X$ will depend on the choice of the set $X$ and not strictly on $|X|$. (For example if $j=k$ then the number of blocks contained in $X$ will be $1$ if $X$ **is** a block of $\mathcal{D}$, and $0$ otherwise.)

Comment: I think I now understand your idea using the complementary Steiner system. I am wondering whether using a $(v,k,\lambda)$-BIBD instead of a Steiner system can make the answer independent of the choice of $X$. The complementary will be a $(v,v-k,b-2r+\lambda)$-BIBD for which we can use the formula you gave for $\lambda_j'$. Do you think there is a lower bound on $\lambda$ such that $\lambda_j'$ is always a constant?

Comment: If a $t$-$(v.k,\lambda)$ has a constant number of blocks containing a $c$-set for some $t < c \leq k$, then it is in fact also a $c$-$(v,k,\lambda^{*})$ design for some $\lambda^{*}$; it can be seen that $\lambda^{*} < \lambda$, so this can't happen for Steiner systems. The same holds if there is some $k \leq c^{\prime} < n-t$ for which there is a constant number of blocks contained in a $c^{\prime}$-set.